# Rebus unsubscribe automatically?

Tags: rebus

At what time does rebus unsubscribe? Is there anything that unsubscribes automatically after a period of time if a subscriber hasn't been running?

I have had some situations where it seems that when the subscriber service has been stopped for a period of time, the publisher doesn't keep sending messages their way. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebus unsubscribes when you `bus.Unsubscribe<SomeMessage>()`.

If you experience that a subscriber suddenly no longer receives published messages, *it is most likely because your publisher is "forgetting" the subscriptions somehow*.

Did you start the publisher with the default in-mem subscription storage? Because that will not survive a restart of the publisher.

You will almost always be interested in having some way of actually persisting the subscriptions, using e.g. SQL Server to do it:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Subscriptions(s => s.StoreInSqlServer(connectionString, "RebusSubscriptions")
                         .EnsureTableIsCreated())
    .(...)
```

If you still experience what seems to be a randomly forgotten subscriber, would it by any chance be because you've renamed or moved the event class?

The subscription is stored in the publisher's subscription storage as a `(eventType, subscriberInputQueue)` tuple, but the actual storing of the `eventType` may vary depending on the chosen subscription storage. I can see that the XML subscription storage [uses the type's assembly-qualified name](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus.Xml/XmlSubscriptionStorage.cs#L160) as its key, whereas the SQL Server subscription storage [uses the type's `FullName`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/Persistence/SqlServer/SqlServerSubscriptionStorage.cs#L69) as the key - iow the chosen subscription storage might have slightly different behavior (which I see is not optimal, but it's a consequence of the way the abstraction is designed).

When the publisher publishes, it will [ask the subscription storage for the subscribers for a given event type](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/src/Rebus/IStoreSubscriptions.cs#L23), so it is this lookup that for some reason does not always return your subscriber's input queue.

Since the XML subscription storage uses assembly-qualified name, it will also be sensitive to version changes of your messages assembly.

I hope this can give you an indication on why you're experiencing dropped subscriptions :)

Comment: I have both used the Xml Storage and the SqlServer storage, so no I am not using the in-mem storage.

Comment: So that is not the issue. I couldn't be sure, but it does seem to me, that this is going on when the subscriber has been stopped (nicely), but there is no explicit code unsubscriping. But obviously it doesn't do this consequently. I just also wanted to make sure that there is no automatically unsubscribe because a service has been "offline" for any amount of time.

Comment: Did you do something that changed either the `FullName` or the `AssemblyQualifiedName` of the type? I've extended the answer with more suggestions as to what might be tricking you :)